# MySQL Retrieve data IF column is not empty

Tags: php, mysql, sql, if-statement, pdo

I have this table:

```
title1  title2   type
---------------------
qwe1    xcv2     3
asd1    tzu      7
fgh1    (empty)  4
```

and I have this query:

```
SELECT `title1` AS `title`, `type`
FROM `table`
UNION
SELECT `title2` AS `title`, `type`
FROM `table`
ORDER BY `title` ASC, type
```

(please see [fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ec9a/5)).

How can I transform this query so that it doesn't display any rows if title2 is empty? Row 1 shouldn't be displayed.

I tried to implement an IF-statement, but I always get a mysql error.

Comment: to display certain rows one have to implement WHERE statement, not IF

Answer (score 0):

This should cover the empty string and null:

```
SELECT `title1` AS `title`, `type`
FROM `table`
UNION
SELECT `title2` AS `title`, `type`
FROM `table` where title2 is not null and title2 <> ''
ORDER BY `title` ASC, type
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use WHERE statement to define condition for your query

```
SELECT `title1` AS `title`, `type`
FROM `table`
WHERE `title1` IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(`title1`) > 0
UNION
SELECT `title2` AS `title`, `type`
FROM `table`
WHERE `title2` IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(`title2`) > 0
ORDER BY `title` ASC, type
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `UNION`, you remove duplicates. Are you sure you don't want to use `UNION ALL`? In addition, is there any reason that you need to have a `title2`? It doesn't seem normalized to me.

```
SELECT title1 AS title, `type`
FROM `table`
UNION ALL
SELECT title2 AS title, `type`
FROM `table`
WHERE title2 IS NOT NULL AND title2 <> ''
```

### [See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3ec9a/26)

Answer (score 0):

I think that, instead to check if `title2 is not null` and `title2 <> ''`, the shortest way is to use COALESCE to convert any Null value to empty, and then check if the result of COALESCE is <> '', like this:

```
SELECT title1 AS title, `type`
FROM `table`
UNION
SELECT title2 AS title, `type`
FROM `table`
WHERE COALESCE(title2, '') <> ''
```

and if you don't need to remove duplicates, i think it's better to use UNION ALL instead of UNION.